# Non-Latin characters in VBA InputBox()

Tags: vba, excel, activex, inputbox

I am using VBA code to get data from user by using InputBox function. I want a user to write in Arabic.

But, when I run it, I found strange characters although I can write in Arabic normally in Excel sheets.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.

You will need to edit your answer to add in examples of the text that fails and the error conditions you are experiencing.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom form, that works as `InputBox`. 
There you would be able to write in any other language than English.

Otherwise you would be getting the `?????????????????????`

Simply add a label element for the input and button elements for <kbd>Ok</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

[image]

In general, this is much better than InputBox, because you can control the `TextAlign` property, which is different in Arabic than in English.

Comment: Thanks Vityata for your help

Comment: @AhmedGamal - welcome :)